# Disabled button not visible in flag dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, flagging

Since a while, it's possible to [retract a flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281010/295232) by opening the flag dialog again and clicking the 'Retract flag' button. Of course, if the flag is already handled, retracting isn't possible. In this case, the MathOverflow site design ***hides*** the button instead of graying it out.

> Can the disabled 'Retract flag' button be displayed in light gray instead of not showing it at all?

---

This is how it looks right now:

[image]

For comparison, here's how it looks like on Mathematics Stack Exchange:

[image]

Comment: Uhh, on MSE the disabled button says "Flag Question" (or Answer), rather than "Retract Flag". But I agree that there is a fundamental difference. The retraction button should only be apparent when there is a flag to retract. Which is the situation on that MSE screenshot.

Comment: I just now tested this on MO, when you flag something and load the flagging dialog again, you have the retraction button available. My guess is that you cannot retract a closure flag once it was halfway through the review queue or something. Which is why the button is disabled.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm pretty sure (from past experience on other sites) that the availability of the retract button just depends on whether the flag is 'waiting for review' or not.

Comment: The issue occurs on The Workplace as well, so I posted a question on the [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297236/295232).

Comment: This issue has been fixed. A fuller explanation can be found [on Meta Stack Exchange.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297254/229714)