# Disabled buttons not visible in /review

Tags: bug, design, review-system

When using the [review queues](https://mathoverflow.net/review), the disabled button has become invisible:

[image]

For example, this is how it looks like for Stack Overflow:

[image]

This issue is maybe related to [Buttons (white-on-light grey) look like they are inactive](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3870/70594); it also looks similar to my previous report [Disabled button not visible in flag dialog](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3281/disabled-button-not-visible-in-flag-dialog) which has been marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). [Here](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3217/121968) is a similar issue on another site.

**EDIT**: there's another site in the network with this bug, so I've posted [a bug report on the main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315031/295232).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the new responsive design has fixed this issue:

[image]